# JS variable have not the value that it should have (with JS, SCSS and Nuxt.js)

Tags: javascript

I have a photo gallery in JavaScript, using Nuxt.js. The problem is that the variable slideIndex should be equal to a number (defined with the .onclick events), and when we look at this variable in the JS console, we see it as undefined. The consequences are that slideIndex is not a number (NaN), so it not corresponds to an image, and so slides[slideIndex-1].style.display returns a TypeError because it's not possible to know the display of nothing.

Here is the js, scss and vue code :

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  let slideIndex;

  // Open PopUp
  document.querySelector(".lienImg1").onclick = function() {
    document.querySelector(".photo-gallery-fullscreen").style.display = "block";
    document.querySelector(".slide-container img:nth-child(1)").style.display = "block";
    slideIndex = 1; // slideIndex should be equal to 1, but is not (undefined)
  };

  document.querySelector(".lienImg2").onclick = function() {
    document.querySelector(".photo-gallery-fullscreen").style.display = "block";
    document.querySelector(".slide-container img:nth-child(2)").style.display = "block";
    slideIndex = 2; // slideIndex should be equal to 2, but is not (undefined)
  };

  document.querySelector(".lienImg3").onclick = function() {
    document.querySelector(".photo-gallery-fullscreen").style.display = "block";
    document.querySelector(".slide-container img:nth-child(3)").style.display = "block";
    slideIndex = 3; // slideIndex should be equal to 3, but is not (undefined)
  };

  // Close PopUp
  document.querySelector(".out").onclick = function() {
    document.querySelector(".photo-gallery-fullscreen").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector(".slide-container img:nth-child(1)").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector(".slide-container img:nth-child(2)").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector(".slide-container img:nth-child(3)").style.display = "none";
    slideIndex = 1;
  };
});

// Gallery Full Screen
let slideIndex;

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Problem : slideIndex is not defined (undefined) --> it's not a number (NaN) --> it not corresponds to an image --> "slides[slideIndex-1].style.display" returns (TypeError)
function showSlides(n) {
  let i;
  let slides = document.querySelectorAll(".photo-fullscreen");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }    
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
// Photo Gallery
.photo-gallery-section {
  margin: 50px 0;

  .photo-gallery {
    width: 80%;
    height: 250px;
    margin: auto;

    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 250px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 250px);
    justify-content: space-between;
    gap: 10px;

    .photo:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .photo:nth-child(1) {
      background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544367567-0f2fcb009e0b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1820&q=80) center center / cover;
    }

    .photo:nth-child(2) {
      background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1575052814086-f385e2e2ad1b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1740&q=80) center center / cover;
    }

    .photo:nth-child(3) {
      background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1524863479829-916d8e77f114?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2670&q=80) center center / cover;
    }
  }

  .photo-gallery-fullscreen {
    display: none;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;

    .slide-container {
      width: fit-content;
      margin: calc(50vh - 225px) auto;
    }

    .slide-container img {
      height: 450px;
      z-index: 3;
      display: none;
    }

    .prev,
    .next {
      cursor: pointer;
      color: #333;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 40px;
      z-index: 3;
      position: absolute;
    }

    .prev {
      margin: calc(50vh - 21px) 0;
      margin-left: 15vw;
      left: 0;
    }

    .next {
      margin: calc(50vh - 21px) 0;
      margin-right: 15vw;
      right: 0;
    }

    .out {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      z-index: 2;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
    <section class="photo-gallery-section" id="photo-gallery-section">
      <h2 class="photo-gallery-title">Gallerie Photo</h2>

      <div class="photo-gallery">
        <div class="photo lienImg1"></div>
        <div class="photo lienImg2"></div>
        <div class="photo lienImg3"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="photo-gallery-fullscreen">
        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 0)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 0)">&#10095;</a>

        <div class="slide-container">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544367567-0f2fcb009e0b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1820&q=80" />
          <img
            src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1575052814086-f385e2e2ad1b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1740&q=80"
            class="photo-fullscreen"
          />
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1524863479829-916d8e77f114?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2670&q=80" />
        </div>

        <div class="out"></div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Thank you very much for your help,
Maxime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`let slideIndex` in the load event function is local to that (anonymous) function., and shadows the global definition underneath the comment `// Gallery Full Screen`.

The simplest solution may be to remove the declaration of `slideIndex` from the load event handler so that the global variable is used by all code.

Comment: Indeed, I removed the declaration of slideIndex from the load event, and it is working now